# Where can I find the RecurGrep command in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vundle

Is there a `Bundle` (for `gmarik/Vundle.vim`) or a other place (website, package, repo) where I can find and install `RecurGrep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a plugin, instead you just need to add the following lines to your `.vimrc` file. I'm not sure where it originally came from sorry.

```vimrc
" simple recursive grep
command! -nargs=1 RecurGrep lvimgrep /<args>/gj ./**/*.* | lopen | set nowrap
command! -nargs=1 RecurGrepFast silent exec 'lgrep! <q-args> ./**/*.*' | lopen
nmap ,R :RecurGrep 
nmap ,r :RecurGrepFast 
nmap ,wR :RecurGrep <cword><CR>
```

After `:RecurGrep` there is a space: `:RecurGrep-> <-` such that you don't have to type it every time you use the mapped shortcut.